# Compare-Object Find Matches and Remove Found from First Object

Tags: powershell, object, compareobject

I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to accomplish this. I have two (JSON) objects, where they have properties that are lists of IPs (the properties are individual IPs). I'm comparing the two object properties to find any matching items and want to remove any matches from the first object (`$JSONConverted`). I believe I can use the remove feature (which I haven't gotten working yet). I'm really wondering if there's a simpler way to accomplish this.

```bsh
$JSONConverted   = Get-Content -Raw -Path Output.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$FWJSONConverted = Get-Content -Raw -Path FWOutput.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$MatchingIPs = Compare-Object -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -ReferenceObject $FWJSONConverted.data.value -DifferenceObject $JSONConverted.data.value

$ListOfMatchingIPs = $MatchingIPs.InputObject

$JSONConverted.data.value | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($IP in $ListOfMatchingIPs) {
        if ($_ -eq $IP) {
            $JSONConverted.remove.($_)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the `$JSONConverted` data:

```json
{
  "number_of_elements": 1134,
  "timeout_type": "LAST",
  "name": "IP List",
  "data": [
    {
      "last_seen": 1486571563476,
      "source": "WORD: WORDS",
      "value": "10.10.10.10",
      "first_seen": 1486397213696
    },
    {
      "last_seen": 1486736205285,
      "source": "WORD: WORDS",
      "value": "10.17.24.22",
      "first_seen": 1486397813280
    },
    {
      "last_seen": 1486637743793,
      "source": "WORD: WORDS",
      "value": "10.11.10.10",
      "first_seen": 1486398713056
    }
  ],
  "creation_time": 1486394698941,
  "time_to_live": "1 years 0 mons 3 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs",
  "element_type":"IP"
}
```

Comment: Do I want to know why you have JSON code in files with the extension .xml?

Comment: Fixed it. The extension made no difference for what I've been trying to accomplish, at least to my knowledge.

Comment: Technically it doesn't make a difference. Still, since Windows associates file handlers via the extension using a mismatching extension is rather sloppy. With that said, what does your input data actually look like? Also, I doubt that `$JSONConverted.remove.($_)` would actually remove anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should suffice (assuming you want to remove the entire child object from the `data` array):

```
$JSONConverted.data = $JSONConverted.data | Where-Object {
    @($FWJSONConverted.data.value) -notcontains $_.value
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seemed to have worked. As when I check $jsonconverted.data.value again, the known matching IP's still exist there. I'm trying to remove the entire object (child object?)from the original $jsonconverted object. I should probably add, that the $jsonconverted object and the $FWJSONConverted object are not identical.

Comment: @MrMr It worked when I tested it with your sample data. Please provide evidence. Also, what PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: I apologize, It looks like I missed the .value after $_. This works great, thank you very much. Any chance you would have a moment to help me understand the @() portion? I understand what is happening generally, but why does the @() work?

Comment: `@()` is the [array subexpression operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators). It forces the result of `$FWJSONConverted.data.value` to an array, even if that (sub)expression yields only one (or no) result. That is required for `-notcontains` to work correctly.